# Having trouble avoiding wakingup immediately after suspend

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I have to disable some event to avoid an immediate wakeup after suspend in my laptop,for instance; the active ones are listed below at `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. At @waltinator 's request I put a pin on the timeline and this is the log result of `sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"`. I am quite unfamiliar with this subject. Can someone help??

```
PEG0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:06.0
RP01      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
RP04      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.3
RP05      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.4
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
TXHC      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.0
TDM0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.2
TRP0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.0
TRP1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

---

This is log results of `sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"`

```
    Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST ModemManager[914]: <info>  [sleep-m>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST google-chrome.desktop[3666]: [3660:>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Activati>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manage>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Successf>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVE>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVE>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing addr>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS mul>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.I>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [17009>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing addr>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS mul>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.I>
lines 1-23...skipping...
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7349] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7351] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST ModemManager[914]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7357] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7359] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST google-chrome.desktop[3666]: [3660:3689:1125/232657.737534:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.1>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 50:78:b3:f8:d2:70 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=50:78:b3:f8:d2:70 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9004] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d2a7:8655:8b38:1172 on wlo1.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::d2a7:8655:8b38:1172.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9276] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9277] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9277] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.28 on wlo1.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.28.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-resolved[692]: wlo1: Bus client set default route setting: no
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-resolved[692]: wlo1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9411] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9420] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST update-notifier[4112]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST update-notifier[4112]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST gnome-shell[1884]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-sleep[5397]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing user space processes
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: Ignoring bogus Namespace Identifiers
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
lines 1-57

Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7349] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7351] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST ModemManager[914]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7357] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7359] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST google-chrome.desktop[3666]: [3660:3689:1125/232657.737534:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.1>
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 50:78:b3:f8:d2:70 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=50:78:b3:f8:d2:70 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9004] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d2a7:8655:8b38:1172 on wlo1.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::d2a7:8655:8b38:1172.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9276] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9277] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9277] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.28 on wlo1.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.28.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-resolved[692]: wlo1: Bus client set default route setting: no
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-resolved[692]: wlo1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9411] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9420] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST update-notifier[4112]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST update-notifier[4112]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST gnome-shell[1884]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-sleep[5397]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing user space processes
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: Ignoring bogus Namespace Identifiers
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
lines 1-57

Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7349] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7351] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST ModemManager[914]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7357] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.7359] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST google-chrome.desktop[3666]: [3660:3689:1125/232657.737534:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by >
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 50:78:b3:f8:d2:70 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=50:78:b3:f8:d2:70 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9004] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d2a7:8655:8b38:1172 on wlo1.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::d2a7:8655:8b38:1172.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9276] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9277] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9277] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.28 on wlo1.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.28.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST avahi-daemon[783]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-resolved[692]: wlo1: Bus client set default route setting: no
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-resolved[692]: wlo1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9411] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Kas 25 23:26:57 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [1700944017.9420] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST update-notifier[4112]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST update-notifier[4112]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST wpa_supplicant[843]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST gnome-shell[1884]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd-sleep[5397]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
Kas 25 23:26:58 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing user space processes
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Kas 25 23:27:01 sskoldas-Summit-E15-A11SCST kernel: nvme nvme0: Ignoring bogus Namespace Identifiers
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the dangerous path to a Well-known Error: Applying a "solution" before diagnosing the problem.

This can often exacerbate the problem state (Make it worse, by stirring your system with a `root` stick).

Diagnostic procedure:

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend/shutdown thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Comment: I got this 'Failed to parse timestamp:'. What can I do in this case?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show us `cat --show-all pin.tmp`. Do not reply via Add Comment.